# if A and B are two sets and E the whole space , show That ( A∪B=E and A∩B=∅ ) ⟺ B=C(A) ⟺ A = C(B)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

this is my first year in college and my second lesson in algebra is sets and i have this question as an application that demands to :
( A∪B=E and A∩B=∅ ) ⟺ B=C(A) ⟺ A = C(B)

I know it's the definition of complement of the set, and that if A= C(B) that show easily that A∩B= ∅ and A∪B=E , but i've a problem with the writing of the proof in a propre way , with both implications  ..
any suggestions please ?

Comment: does contraposition gonna work ?

Comment: Hi @Newbie, welcome to math.stackexchange. Normally to prove "$\iff$" statements one tries to prove the $\rightarrow$ direction and the $\leftarrow$ direction separately. You already got one, namely the  $\leftarrow$ one. For the $\rightarrow$ I'd recommend to try a contradiction: "what if A wasn't the complement of B" ,  if such statement leads to a contradiction, then you have that $A$ not being the complement of $B$ was the problem and thus conclude.

Comment: Some steps can be, first assume $[(A \cup B=E) \land (A \cap B = \emptyset)]$, then from this assumption show that $B=C(A) \Rightarrow A=C(B)$ and later similarly $A=C(B) \Rightarrow B=C(A)$. Here you have finished the "$\Rightarrow$" part,then assume $B=C(A) \Leftrightarrow A=C(B)$ and from this assumption show that $A \cup B = E$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ both holds. Then you have show the "$\Leftarrow$" part and finished the proof.